# writing csv to tarfile but with no extension inside

Tags: python, tarfile

I'm trying to create a .csv file and then create a .gz file with the previous csv inside. The problem is that the .gz file is created with a file with the correct file name but without the .csv extension and I don't know how to solve it.

This is the relevant code:

```
new_file_name = 'test'
data = [['some','test'],['data','strings']]
csv_fname = '%s.csv' % new_file_name
tar_fname = '%s.gz' % new_file_name

with open(csv_fname, 'wb') as csvfile:
    swriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for row in data:
        swriter.writerow(row)      

print 'creating archive'
out = tarfile.open(tar_fname, 'w:gz')
try:
    print 'adding %s' % csv_fname
    out.add(csv_fname)
finally:
    print 'closing'
    out.close()
```

Comment: I think your tarfile open should be something like `tarfile.open(name=tar_fname, mode='w:gz')`.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't change anything. Same result.

Comment: So I ran your code and it seems to work for me. after running your code, the command `tar tvf test.gz` produces `-rw-rw-r-- jra/jra          25 2018-07-19 20:42 test.csv`